# Why aren't the components re-rendering after a state change in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get data from the Coin Market Cap API and display the information in some very basic cards. I have tried many things and have comments showing what I have tested. Please help.

This is the Parent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import CardList from './CardList';
// a test file for starting off.
// import { coinObj } from './coinObj';


class App extends Component {
  //I have tried with props here too, but don't know why that would matter in the case.
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      coinObj: [],
    }
  }

  //Get information from coinmarketcap api.
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(parsedJSON => this.setState(
        {coinObj: parsedJSON.data}
      ))
      .catch(error => console.log('Something went wrong!', error))

      // .then(coinObj => console.log(coinObj))
  }
  //render cards with data from api
  //The state is changed when I run this with the React Dev tools but it does not render new info.
  render() {
    let { coinObj } = this.state;
    //This console loads twice as expected and the second time it has the object from coinmarketplace.
    console.log(coinObj);

    return !coinObj.length ?
      <h2>Loading</h2> :    
    (
      <div>
        <h1>Coins and Stocks</h1>
        <CardList coinObj={ coinObj } />
      </div>
    );

    //I use this below to try and force the program forward but then I cannot read any values from the object I put in state.
    /*return (
      <div>
        <h1>Coins and Stocks</h1>
        <CardList coinObj={ coinObj } />
      </div>
    );
    */  
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is one Child:

```
import React from 'react';
import Card from './Card';

const CardList = ({coinObj}) => {
    //This array holds the id of the coins I am interested in.
    const coinsIdArray = [1, 1027, 1958, 2577];
    //This shows me the first object in my object of objects when the cards are commented bottom is out.
    console.log(coinObj[1]);
    //Test if I can grab a value from it and it says that name is undefined but it is clearly their the example above.
    // console.log(coinObj[1].name);


    // send data to the card
    return (
        <div className="container-fluid row">
            <Card name={coinObj[coinsIdArray[0]].name} rank={coinObj[coinsIdArray[0]].rank} price={coinObj[coinsIdArray[0]].quotes["USD"].price} percentChange24={coinObj[coinsIdArray[0]].quotes["USD"].percent_change_24h} />
            <Card name={coinObj[coinsIdArray[1]].name} rank={coinObj[coinsIdArray[1]].rank} price={coinObj[coinsIdArray[1]].quotes["USD"].price} percentChange24={coinObj[coinsIdArray[1]].quotes["USD"].percent_change_24h} />
            <Card name={coinObj[coinsIdArray[2]].name} rank={coinObj[coinsIdArray[2]].rank} price={coinObj[coinsIdArray[2]].quotes["USD"].price} percentChange24={coinObj[coinsIdArray[2]].quotes["USD"].percent_change_24h} />
            <Card name={coinObj[coinsIdArray[3]].name} rank={coinObj[coinsIdArray[3]].rank} price={coinObj[coinsIdArray[3]].quotes["USD"].price} percentChange24={coinObj[coinsIdArray[3]].quotes["USD"].percent_change_24h} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default CardList;
```

Final Child:

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = ({name, rank, price, percentChange24}) => {
    // destructering the data from api to be used.
    // should break up props first but I am trouble shooting other stuff.....................!
    // const {name, rank, price, percentChange24} = props;
    return (
        <div className="card shadow" style={{width: '18rem'}}>
            <img alt='coin/stock logo' src='https://en.bitcoin.it/w/images/en/2/29/BC_Logo_.png' className="mx-auto card-img-top w-50 h-50" />
            <div className="card-body">
                <h2 className="card-title text-center">{name}</h2>
                <h5 className="text-center">{`Rank: ${rank}`}</h5>
            </div>
            <ul className="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li className="list-group-item">{`Price: $${price.toFixed(2)}`}</li>
                <li className="list-group-item">{`Change over 24hrs: ${percentChange24}%`}</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    )
}

export default Card;
```

My first problem was getting the information to pass through to the component from the parent. I was getting an error saying the coinObj[1].name was undefined. I came to the conclusion that it was trying to get the information before the api had returned. Now I cannot get it to re-render which leave me wondering if I will still have that problem after this is corrected. Please and thank you for any help.

Comment: What does your `parsedJSON.data` data look like that you get from your request? It might be that it's an object and not an array. Since objects have no `length` property like arrays have, `!coinObj.length` would still evaluate to `true`.

Comment: It is an object for sure.

Comment: Alright, great. `coinObj` is an empty array in your state initially. Maybe you can set it to `null` initially and check for `coinObj === null` instead?

Comment: Oh YES! Thank you so much! You are amazing! Is there anyway I can high five you or give you positive marks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `parsedJSON.data` that you get from your network request and put in your state is an object. All objects don't have the `length` property like arrays do, so `!coinObj.length` will still evaluate to `true` once the request has finished.

You could instead e.g. change the initial value from an empty array to `null` and check for that in your render method:

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    coinObj: null
  };

  // ...

  render() {
    let { coinObj } = this.state;

    return coinObj === null ? (
      <h2>Loading</h2>
    ) : (
      <div>
        <h1>Coins and Stocks</h1>
        <CardList coinObj={coinObj} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```